# Using SCP command to download logs from Linux server to local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp, tail

How can I download last 10 lines of access log from remote server to local machine using 'SCP' command to display only. I have tried to pipe tail command with scp but couldn't download last 10 lines.

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't download last 10 lines" ? What's the error ?

Comment: You could just `ssh user@host tail -n10 /path/to/logfile > ./mylocallogfile` aswell if scp isnt working for some reason.

Comment: its actually downloading whole access.log file. but i just need to download last 10 lines of that log file to my local machine.

Comment: Then the ssh command will achieve that. It calls `tail` on the remote server.

Comment: Thank you. The ssh command worked and i am able to download just last 10 lines of log using that command.

Comment: hi git-bruh can help me once again. Can i directly transfer files from remote server and not from local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [daggy](https://docs.daggy.dev/#getting-started).

Create sources config with files that you want to transfers and remote servers, from which you want to transfer (heads.yaml):

```yaml
    aliases:  
        - &my_commands
            file1:
                exec: haed -n 10 file1
                extension: log
            file2:
                exec: head -n 10 file2
                extension: log
            
        - &ssh_auth
            user: {{env_USER}}
            passphrase: {{env_PASSWORD}}
                
    sources:
        localhost:
            type: local
            commands: *my_commands
        remotehost:
            host: 192.168.1.9
            type: ssh2
            parameters: *ssh_auth
            commands: *my_commands
        remotehost2:
            host: 192.168.1.10
            type: ssh2
            parameters: *ssh_auth
            commands: *my_commands
```

Run daggy:

```sh
    daggy heads.yaml
```